# Lazily defining constants in a Rails Initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initializer

I have an initializer which loads a YML file, parses it through ERB, and stores the resulting hash in a constant that's accessible app-wide

```
# config/initializers/links.rb

LINKS = YAML.load(
  ERB.new(File.read(Rails.root.join("config", "links.yml"))).result
)
```

The reason for the ERB is that some elements in the YML file rely on URL helpers and need to be templated -

```
# config/links.yml
---
footer:
  homepage:
    personal: <%= personal_path %>
    root: <%= root_path %>
    foo: bar
    ....
```

The problem is that when the initializer runs, it fails because the Rails environment has not been initialized (I think?) and so those helper definitions don't exist.

To work around that, I lazily read that file so it only gets parsed when it's called for the first time (which is presumably after we've loaded the `environment`)

```
# config/initializers/links.rb

def links
  unless defined? LINKS
    links = YAML.load(
      ERB.new(File.read(Rails.root.join("config", "links.yml"))).result
    )
    const_set("LINKS", links)
  end

  LINKS
end
```

But now I'm getting an error because `const_set` is not a defined method.

1. How do I set the constant in this scenario?
2. Does this method ensure that the constant is defined globally (i.e. app-wide) the first time it's called? If `links()` is called from a view/controller/model/etc... I wouldn't want that constant to get set within the context of just that class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I suppose the reason for using that is the performance, I think much better is to create a helper method with CacheStore used:

```
module LinksHelper
  def links
    Rails.cache.fetch("links_helper/links", expires_in: 1.hour) do
      YAML.load(
        ERB.new(File.read(Rails.root.join("config", "links.yml"))).result
      )
    end
  end
end
```

and then you should only include this helper when it is necessary and not included by default.

Comment: Thanks! I like the approach - where would I define that `module`? Also for curiosity, is there a way to still do it with my originally intended approach of setting the constant?

Comment: You can put it into app/helpers as usual. Of course you may change all body of this module with `LINKS = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read(Rails.root.join("config", "links.yml"))).result) unless defined? LINKS` to define a constant, but it will be reloaded in every request. I have not an idea how to define it in an initializer having helper methods available.